# Examples of Alexandrov spaces with sec>=-1 and first eigenvalue (n-1)^2/4

Tags: alexandrov-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Could someone give examples of non-Riemannian manifolds that are Alexandrov spaces with $\mathrm{sec}\geq-1$ and the first eigenvalue equal to $(n-1)^2/4$?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but one might be able to take $\mathbb{H}^n$ modulo an appropriate finite group. It would help if you could give a reference for the definition of the eigenvalue for a non-Riemannian Alexandrov space. 

Comment: "sharp spectral gap and Li-Yau's estimate on Alexandrov spaces" ,the first page you can see the definition